# What do I need to do to make redo restore text after undo in Qt QPlainTextEdit

Tags: python, pyside6, undo-redo, qplaintextedit

When I type into a QPlainTextEdit window and then type CTRL+Z to undo the undo works fine.  But then when I type CTRL+Y to redo the undo nothing happens.  What am I missing that redo does not work?

Here is my test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Redo (CTRL+Y) does not restore text after Undo (CTRL+Z)
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPlainTextEdit
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize
class ExampleWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.b.insertPlainText("example text 1\nexample text 2\nexample text 3")
        self.b.resize(440,240)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QMainWindow()
    w.setMinimumSize(QSize(440, 240))    
    w.setWindowTitle("QPlainTextEdit undo/redo example") 
    edit = QPlainTextEdit(w)
    edit.insertPlainText("example line 1\nexample line 2\nexample line 3")
    edit.resize(440,240)
    print("undoRedoEnabled: ", edit.isUndoRedoEnabled())
    w.show()

    sys.exit( app.exec() )
```

Comment: What OS? `Ctrl+Y` is only common on Windows (luckily, as it's really uncomfortable), other OSs use `Ctrl+Shift+Z` instead, and that's what Qt undo stack *mainly* uses, based on [QKeySequence standard shortcuts](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qkeysequence.html#standard-shortcuts). Check if you're not using that keyboard combination for something else in your program, and, if you *do* use Windows, ensure that you don't have a background program that takes control over keyboard input. Also, you must **always** use a [central widget](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework) on QMainWindow.

Comment: I used Linux.  Redo is available with the correct keystroke.  The standard shortcuts table https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante cites correctly shows Ctrl+Shift+Z.

Answer (score 0):

The correct keystroke for the OS must be used.